# Does POSIX require comparison operators for `pthread_key_t`, `pthread_once_t` and `pthread_t`?

Tags: c++, c, types, pthreads, posix

The standards document for `sys/types.h` (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html), says "There are no defined comparison or assignment operators for the following types:", then lists a bunch of types. However, some of the non-arithmetic (or rather not-necessarily arithmetic) types are missing from that list. Notably, `pthread_key_t`, `pthread_once_t` and `pthread_t` are missing. It seems odd to say "these types don't have assignment and comparison operators" when that's already implied for non-arithmetic types. Does this mean that conforming implementations must provide comparison and assignment operators for those 3 types?

Comment: POSIX doesn't have to explicitly say that there are no defined comparison or assignment operators for any particular type.  It is sufficient that it avoids defining them or making any provisions that require such operators to be defined.  The quoted text is inherently informative, not normative.  In particular, that cannot be interpreted as a prohibition on implementations; rather, it is a statement about what POSIX itself does or does not define.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: Comparison or assignment of `pthread_key_t` and such may or may not be valid, depending on the particular pthreads implementation. Comparison or assignment of `pthread_mutex_t` and such must never be valid.**

No, it doesn't mean that conforming implementations have to provide comparison or assignment operators for those types. In fact, if the implementation defines one of those types as a struct, a comparison operator would be impossible to provide. POSIX builds on C not C++, and C doesn't allow comparison operations on structs.

However, conforming implementations aren't required to use structs. If they chose to, they are free to use arithmetic types for example. If they did use an arithmetic type to define one of `pthread_key_t`, `pthread_once_t` or `pthread_t`, then comparison and assignment operations on that type would likely be valid. (However, an application shouldn't rely on them if it wants to be portable).

This is not the case with `pthread_mutex_t` for example. The standard doesn't specify how `pthread_mutex_t` should be defined, so an implementation could theoretically use an arithmetic type to define `pthread_mutex_t`. However, the standard is saying here that comparison and assignment operations between instances of `pthread_mutex_t` must be forbidden.

Presumably the reasoning for this is similar to why the C++ standard goes out of it's way to forbid copying instances of `std::mutex`. Copying a mutex is a nonsensical operation. The same is true for most/all of the other types the standard forbids comparison or assignment of.